# What is the significance of these lines in the explicit Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian?

Tags: computational-physics, hamiltonian, second-quantization, bose-hubbard-model

I was doing some 2nd quantization computational physics and as my first system i decided to build up a Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{k} \left\{ \tau_k(a^\dagger_{k} a_{k+1} + a_{k} a^\dagger_{k+1}) + \frac{U}{2}(n_{k}^2 - n_{k}) + \mu n_{k} \right\}.
$$

with 6 Bosons in 7 Sites. 924x924 matrix. The reason I went for a larger system is because the matrix was showing very interesting fractal patterns which I wanted to see how they repeat at larger scales.

This beauty comes up

[image]

We see first the diagonal lines parallel to the main one. They repeat and double for every step we take towards the main diagonal. Another super interesting property I noticed is that if we build an imaginary horizontal line (relative to x-y) from the tip of one of these off diagonal strips, its length from the main diagonal is exactly the strip length -1 the for each of them.

Another interesting fractal are the 2 main curved strips that connect the tips of every first large off-diagonal strip. A closer look at this we can see the curve shape fractals into itself too on every step.

The eigenvalues spectrum looks as follows

[image]

but it has a lot of steps for the next eigenvalues as well, there are many jumps

So is there a physical reason Hamiltonian shaped like this?